# Ошибка в console при подключении bootstrap 4

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

[image: ошибка]

Здравствуйте, подключил к теме Wordpress бутстрап 4 и вот такую ошибку выдает консоль. В чем её беда не знаю. Вот функция подключения скриптови css

```
function playground__scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.min.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'playground-layout-1', get_stylesheet_uri() );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'playground__scripts' );
```

В header ничего не подключал. Кто сталкивался и знает как решить эту проблему и чем эта проблема чревата?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Подключите `popper.js`

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'popper', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.6/popper.min.js');
```